# Composer Require Exceeds Memory Limits

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, packagist

I am trying to run `composer require` and it is giving me this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 129

Fatal error: Allowed memory size of 2147483648 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 4096 bytes) in phar:///usr/local/bin/composer/src/Composer/DependencyResolver/RuleSetGenerator.php on line 129

Check https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md#memory-limit-errors for more info on how to handle out of memory errors.
```

When I run `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"` I can see that my memory limit is set to `2048M` which should be more than enough. I tried running it like this `COMPOSER_MEMORY_LIMIT=-1 composer require` but it just gives me this:

```
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Killed
```

I have tried restarting my computer and that didn't work either. It is worth mentioning that `composer update` and `composer install` work just fine.

I am running Composer version `1.8.6`.

Does anyone know what I can do here?

Comment: Step one would probably be to use a current version of Composer. `composer self-update`

Comment: I have tried that but it doesn't fix the problem

Comment: Then I would follow the steps given in one of the many answers to the duplicate.

Comment: I've tried most of them

Comment: Please share more details, like the current state of `composer.json`  and the **exact** command you are running that triggers that error